AmazonConnect Script in LWC
I want to implement the below line in LWC and show the bubble icon in community portal for Chat.
Script from AmazonConnect
 <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(w, d, x, id){
        s=d.createElement('script');
        s.src='https://dg9yx063wiiht.cloudfront.net/amazon-connect-chat-interface-client.js';
        s.async=1;
        s.id=id;
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        w[x] =  w[x] || function() { (w[x].ac = w[x].ac || []).push(arguments) };
      })(window, document, 'amazon_connect', '5338d219-92c7-427e-8b10-26a8f4dfb3d1');
      amazon_connect('styles', { openChat: { color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#826359'}, closeChat: { color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#940eb9'} });
      amazon_connect('snippetId', 'QVFJREFIaUpTVGJkNWhNc0Q1WHpHYnFQTkJyYXN0.....=');
      amazon_connect('supportedMessagingContentTypes', [ 'text/plain', 'text/markdown' ]);
    </script>

Below is the code I tried in LWC. After this I am not able to move forward. I need some help in fixing this issue.
LWC Code
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
export default class AmazonChatScript extends LightningElement {
renderedCallback() {

    loadScript(this, AmazonConnectChatInterface);
    loadScript(this, ACChatInterface);
    loadScript(this, ACChat);
}

    loadAmazonConnectScript() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://dg9yx063wiiht.cloudfront.net/amazon-connect-chat-interface-client.js'; 
    
}
}


I posted this question because I don't know the answers. People in this community give negative points and try to close the post. Before giving a negative point please comment on the reason so I can correct it.

You can't implement inline scripts in LWC, either directly or by using document.createElement. If you're trying to do this in Lightning Experience, it simply will not be possible. You would need to use a Visualforce page, instead. If you're doing this in a Digital Experience, you can embed custom scripts in the header in Builder | Settings | Advanced | Edit Head Markup.

Hello @sfdcfox thanks for your reply. I tried that it didn't work.
